# how to write my own function that prints back trace

Tags: c, backtrace

How to write a C function to print back trace till that function is called.
I don't want to use any library.I would  like to write my own code to do that job.
Can anyone please inputs to achieve this task?

Comment: What platform & compiler are you using?

Comment: Not possible in portable C, unless you instrument the source code.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write such a function in portable C, and you can't write it without knowing specific platform and calling conventions used by your compiler. Therefore your question (currently) lacks all the details one would need to answer it.

If you want to know how backtrace() works in general, you can study any number of implementations available.

If you want to implement one from scratch (homework?), study the calling convention for your platform.

Answer (score 1):

There's no portable way to do this, but gcc provides a halfway-clean way to do it with `__builtin_return_address` and friends.